# MS Crypto API does not enrcypt/decrypt Japanese characters

Tags: character-encoding, vb6, cryptography

We have a VB6 program that encrypts a set of characters ente On a western Win OS computer, the encrypted string is decrypted back ok. But on Japanese computer, it does not work, and is decoded as bunch of ????. Both input, and output (decoded) textboxes are set to MS UI Gothic with Japanese scripts. Part of the code is given below. The sample input is also given.

Input/output:

```
inputStr = 機帰帰
outputStr= 0Y365H
finalStr=  ???
```

Part of the code:

```
Private Const IC_CONST_INST_KEY_ENCRYPT_STR = "41S81U4AYYPGZDNXKWMPGK0PMDS"
Private Sub cmdEncrypt_Click()
Dim inputStr As String
Dim outputStr As String
Dim finalStr As String
Dim sUnicodeValue, sAsciiValue

    inputStr = txtUInit.Text

    outputStr = EncryptString(inputStr, IC_CONST_INST_KEY_ENCRYPT_STR)
    txtUEncrypt.Text = outputStr

    finalStr = DecryptString(outputStr, IC_CONST_INST_KEY_ENCRYPT_STR)
    txtUDecrypt.Text = finalStr

End Sub
```

Comment: There's no encryption code there, nothing to show how bytes are converted to characters and back again -- in short you have shown the code that is most likely to contain the problem.

Comment: The problem is how you convert characters to bytes. If you use UTF-8 or UTF-16 is should work. If you use ASCII it'll obviously fail.

Comment: Thank you CodesInChaos. That was all I needed. After finding the necessary codes to do the conversion, it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

VB6 cannot deal with the unicode Japanese characters correctly, you would need to convert from unicode to ASCII before running your encryption procedures.

Comment: It can, it uses unicode internally. It DOES however do codepage conversion at the edges where it interfaces with declare functions and most native file I/O. The native UI controls are also not unicode aware but will handle anything in the local codepage.